# Why we can set "var name = null" with no error

Tags: android, kotlin, null, kotlin-null-safety

I just started learning Kotlin and I found a problem I can't understand about Null Safety in Kotlin. I read that variable can't hold null value.

So I made some test about this

```
var name:String = "Albert"
name = null //error
```

Until I try this

```
var name = null //with no error
```

I don't know why I can set `var name = null` with no error.

Comment: _"I read that variable can't hold null value"_. If that variable has a non-nullable type, yes. But `var name = null` probably gives `name` the type `Any?`, which is a nullable type.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Setting value without mentioning a type as null means it is a nothing type.

`var item = null // "Nothing" type`

The above item is of `Nothing?` type